# Facebook API - "assureEndpoint is being deprecated"

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

Trying to use a package to handle my requests to the Facebook API. Getting this error, and not sure where to start.

Here is the package:
https://github.com/edbizarro/laravel-facebook-ads

Here is what i'm doing...

```
$adsApi = FacebookAds::init($accessToken);
$adAccounts = $adsApi->adAccounts();
$adAccounts->all(['account_id', 'balance', 'name']);
```

Here is the error:

```
ErrorException (E_USER_DEPRECATED)
assureEndpoint is being deprecated, please try not to use this in new code.
```

Comment: Pls check out PHP Facebook SDK, the official Facebook API: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk. Maybe it has the feature that you need.

Comment: @KevinBui He can use the Facebook Graph SDK for making the calls by the SDK functions , but since he is using Business SDK for FacebookAds ( which have specific functions already available which we can use instead of using request functions from  the Graph SDK ), will need to use the newer functions instead of the deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **getEndpoint** instead of this.

They have mentioned this in the sdk files  on line 360 of 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookAds/Object/AbstractCrudObject.php

```
 /**
 * @deprecated
 * deprecate with getEndpoint
 * @param string $prototype_class
 * @param string $endpoint
 * @return string
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */

 protected function assureEndpoint($prototype_class, $endpoint) {
 .....
 }
```